Jackson: TypeIdResolver implementation leads to circular dependency to the model class
I have a class hierarchy that needs to be serialized and deserialized with Jackson.
My parent class is named PersonModel and the two subclasses are LegalPersonModel and NaturalPersonModel.
So, I created an implementation of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeIdResolver with name PersonModelTypeResolver . This implements the necessary serialization/deserialization logic. I then connect the two using this annotation in my model class:
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CUSTOM, property = "person-type")
@JsonTypeIdResolver(PersonModelTypeResolver.class) // circular dependency :(
public class PersonModel { ... }

The problem is that PersonModelTypeResolver needs to reference the PersonModel class. There is no way around this due to the implementation specifics.
So I have a circular dependency between my model class and my TypeIdResolver implementation.
Is there a way to avoid the @JsonTypeIdResolver annotation in my model class? Maybe setup the connection between PersonModelTypeResolverand PersonModel in my object-mapper configuration?
